# Save JavaScript Video Blob to File on Server with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, video, ffmpeg

How is a video blob (in JavaScript) sent to server using AJAX and saved as a file with PHP?

I know an image can be, with the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$img = $_POST['imageBase64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);

file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
?>
```

but I would like to know how this can be done with a video blob, so I can use it with FFmpeg.